# Openlayers - how to make labels display larger and more legible in hybrid view on map - street, city/town, state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox, gis, openlayers

Difficulty viewing street names in satellite view on the openlayers map with mapbox tilelayer.  The font is smaller than it was in the google maps and seems to blend in to the map, making it tough to read.

comparison of satellite view on [Google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfrZK.jpg) Vs.
[Openlayers/mapbox map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAgqF.jpg)

I poked around in Mapbox’s website and found a “satellite streets” option that looks much better than what we’re currently using.  We should see what it would take to move to this version for our satellite basemap.

See “Satellite Streets” here: [Mapbox Satellite: global base map & satellite imagery](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/satellite)

Interactive demo here:  [Mapbox Satellite Streets](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA#17.04/42.21003/-71.467365)

Here is my code that I used to setup layers:

```
hybridLayer: new TileLayer({
                source: new XYZ({
                    url:
                        "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=" +
                        mapBoxAccessKey,
                }),
                visible: false,
            }),

            satelliteLayer: new TileLayer({
                source: new XYZ({
                    url:
                        "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=" +
                        mapBoxAccessKey,
                }),
                visible: false,
            }),
```

Comment: will that answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043490/11971765

Comment: The display quality will be better if you specify the correct `tileSize: 512,` in the source options as OpenLayers defaults to 256.

Comment: It was in docs all along (note to self: RTFM)

It works way better. Thank you both!